# Remove event handler with code

Tags: c#, reflection, event-handling

An event handler can be removed with the following code in the button click event.

```cs
Button btn = new Button();
this.Controls.Add(btn);
btn.Click += (o, x) =>
{
    Button b = o as Button;
    FieldInfo eventclick = typeof(Control).GetField("EventClick", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    object eventValue = eventclick.GetValue(b);
    PropertyInfo events = b.GetType().GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    EventHandlerList eventHandlerList = (EventHandlerList)events.GetValue(b, null);
    eventHandlerList .RemoveHandler(eventValue, eventHandlerList [eventValue]);
    MessageBox.Show("Test");
};
```

But I want to remove the event handler from the vgridcontrols CellValueChanged event. What do I have to write for "EventClick" in the following?

```
FieldInfo eventclick = typeof(Control).GetField(
    "EventClick",
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Comment: Attribution is required at SO.  Not linking the answer that you found actually prevents you from getting a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot *reliably* remove an event handler from an event unless you already have an "equal" delegate you can use with `-=` in the normal way.

Getting fields with reflection and hacking around at them is a clear violation of encapsulation *and* makes your code extremely fragile. I would *strongly* recommend against doing it.

It's not clear what you mean by "vgridcontrols" (`DataGridView`?) but whatever solution you come up with is bound to be implementation-specific - and that implementation could easily change with the next version of whatever it is.

Instead, put time into coming up with a design where either you don't need to remove the event handler at all, or you keep a reference to the handler and can remove it in the normal way.

Answer (score 0):

This is VB.NET, but you can modify it easily to C#.  This is what you want:

```
'Remove the handler from the cell value changed
Dim gv As DataGridView = Me.equipmentGridView
Dim fInf As FieldInfo = GetType(DataGridView).GetField("EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWCELLVALUECHANGED", BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
Dim del As Object = fInf.GetValue(gv)
Dim pInf As PropertyInfo = gv.GetType().GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
Dim evList As EventHandlerList = pInf.GetValue(gv, Nothing)
evList.RemoveHandler(del, evList(del))
```